# Should we generate chain spec only on corresponding servers?

Tags: polkadot, rococo, chainspec

This might be a weird question. We are preparing our parachain for Polkadot. We have deployed our parachain on testnet, which we have connected with Rococo.

We have generated chain specs for testnet and mainnet on our testnet server. Our plan is to use this mainnet spec(which we have generated on testnet server) on mainnet server.

Can we use this spec or we have to create chain spec only on mainnet server?

Can anyone please help me to provide this information? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, build spec is just build the chain genesis state from the given genesis config.

It doesn't like benchmark.

You can do that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the answer provided is correct.

Your chain specification is not the same than your node specification. The former identifies the chain you will be launching or connecting to, this details genesis state, network id, bootnodes, properties and more info as such.

On the other side, for the runtime your network will be running you want to run [benchmarks](https://docs.substrate.io/test/benchmark/), and from the results of these benchmarks you will be able to provide "required" node specifications (ram, cpu, disk space...). But running benchmarks is when you want to be a bit more cautions on what hardware these are running, as that will affect the results.